# How deep is the Win32 message queue?

Tags: winapi, message-queue

How many messages does the queue for a standard window hold? What happens when the queue overflows?

The documentation for `GetMessage` and relatives doesn't say anything about this, and `PeekMessage` only gives you a yes/no for certain classes of messages, not a message count.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa925082.aspx) says that the queues are implemented using memory-mapped files, and that there is no message count limit, but that page is about WinCE. Does this apply to desktop Win32 as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

10000 by default, but it can be adjusted via the registry.

If queue overflows, PostMessage fails.

Documentation here:

[`PostMessage` function on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944.aspx)

Comment: That covers 2000/XP - any idea about Vista?

Comment: I just looked at the registry key listed in that article on a Vista Business SP1 machine, and it's set to 10000. I don't know if that's the only factor in determining the queue length on Vista, though.

Comment: I don't *KNOW* but it would be unlikely to be different.   Vista isn't that revolutionary, I don't think...

Comment: One more thing though - if you are thinking of using the message queue as, um, a queue that's being fed by another thread, I think you'll disappointed by the results.   You'll end up with a unresponsive GUI.  Our company has a lot of experience with exactly this failed designed technique.

Comment: Hello Corey, thank you for the answer. The mentioned limit and the registry key (which can be adjusted) work for Windows 8 as well.

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the MSDN article, if you need to worry about the size of the message queue, you might be better off redesigning your application.

Comment: In this case, we're on the other side of the queue; our device driver is posting the messages, and a toy Flash application was bogging down after a few minutes.