# Can I monitor the size of a thread's message queue?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, message-queue

Our application is getting a System Call Failed RPC error from DCOM (`0x80010100`), we suspect that the target thread's message queue is full (although I'm not convinced this is ture). I know the queue is [limited to `10,000` messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123323/how-deep-is-the-win32-message-queue) and I want to see if we're close to this number in the common cases. Is there a way to monitor the size of a thread's message queue?

The most promising option I found was [`GetQueueStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644940(VS.85).aspx) but this doesn't include the number of messages in the queue only their types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of any way of monitoring the size of the queue (short of using a kernel debugger and groveling in the internal Win32Thread data structure at TIB+[0x40], which I hardly recommend).

For debugging purposes, to check if the queue is full when you get the error, try doing a PostThreadMessage.  If it's full, the call should fail with GetLastError() == 0x718. (Not enough quota is available to process this command.)