# Amount of events queued up? (Win32 event queue)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm implementing a cross-platform 'completePending' function for an event loop class that should simply parse **n** events that are in the queue. (**n** is grabbed at function start and only **n** events are parsed.)

So I leisurely strolled off into the sunset only to find myself in msdn, looking for a <strike>XEventsQueued()</strike> DWORD WINAPI WinQueuedEvents(__in_opt DWORD). But I could not seem to find one. I began to question the existence of such a function in the win32 api at all! And so I cometh to the wonderful abode of coders that is stackoverflow in search of answers.

As far as I know GetMessage() blocks untill a message is received. So if there isn't a GetPending() i should just peek and get while there are messages for a not-nice alternative?

Comment: I can't find any documentation on `XQueuedEvents`.  Is that the correct spelling?

Comment: I was trying to be funny by showing my superior X11/Xlib knowledge (unix'es)

Comment: Yeah, I realize you were asking for a Windows equivalent to some function you know from X11.  So I wanted to read exactly what that function does... but couldn't find it.

Comment: Wow, google search already finds this page when you search XQueuedEvents... heh I might have failed at remembering.

Comment: It's actually **XEventsQueued** heh

Comment: thanks, looking up the man page now

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256734/can-i-monitor-the-size-of-a-threads-message-queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions that don't block until you get (just) a windows message include:

- `PeekMessage`
- `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`
- `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`

Please note that you can pass `PM_REMOVE` to `PeekMessage` to have a non-blocking `GetMessage`.

And also note that sent messages aren't returned by these functions, they are immediately dispatched.

Comment: Will your answer expand even more? I'm curious. It's like 3.5lines/1min expansion! I guess there isn't 'getpending' function in windows. So yeah, I'll do PeekMessage + GetMessage then.

Comment: @Eximius: You shouldn't need to call `GetMessage` after `PeekMessage` if you use `PM_REMOVE`.

Comment: And yeah, my answer would have expanded more, except MSDN's page for `PeekMessage` won't load.  Problem on their server.  I was checking whether the behavior for sent messages was the same for both.